# Como gestionar los formatos al exportar a csv en R

Tags: r

Quiero exportar a csv un dataframe con una serie de importes
[image: df]

Los importes no tienen separador de miles y los decimales los separa con un punto

uso esta instrucción

```
write.csv(dfCosteHoras,"CosteHoras.csv")
```

y en las opciones tengo especificado que se use UTF-8
[image: utf]

Cuando importo en Excel el csv generado
[image: excel]

Los acentos no los entinde y los importes tampoco me convuerte un valor de 11050.08 en 11050085

Alguna idea?

Un saludo

Comment: Cuando generas el archivo csv editarlo con notpad o algún editor de texto y revisa si los acentos están para diferenciar si es problema al generar el archivo o al leerlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que Excel o Libreoffice con formato regional en español entienda, debes exportar con la coma como el separador decimal y el punto y coma o el tabulador ("\t") como separador de campo.
Usa `write.csv2(dfCosteHoras,"CosteHoras.csv")`
Para los acentos, en Windows debes usar el codificado windows-1252 o CP-, no UTF-8